How to Generate Dilithium Keys with `liboqs-go` and Convert Them to PEM Format for OpenSSL
I am trying to using the liboqs-go library to generate cryptographic keys with post-quantum algorithms and need to use these keys with OpenSSL to generate CSRs and certificates. However, I'm facing challenges with initializing the signer, generating keys, and especially converting them into a PEM format that OpenSSL can use.
Here's what I have tried so far:
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "github.com/open-quantum-safe/liboqs-go/oqs"
)

func generateKeys() ([]byte, []byte, error) {
    // Initialize the signature algorithm, assuming `Dilithium2` is supported.
    signer := oqs.Signature{}
    err := signer.Init("dilithium2", nil)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, err
    }
    defer signer.Clean()

    publicKey, err := signer.GenerateKeyPair()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, err
    }
    secretKey := signer.ExportSecretKey()

    return publicKey, secretKey, nil
}

func main() {
    publicKey, secretKey, err := generateKeys()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error generating keys: %v", err)
    }

    // Assume some function to write keys to disk (not shown here)
    _ = ioutil.WriteFile("public.key", publicKey, 0644)
    _ = ioutil.WriteFile("private.key", secretKey, 0644)
}


I'm facing challenges with initializing the signer, generating keys... What does that mean in concrete terms? Also, the library has examples, e.g. https://github.com/open-quantum-safe/liboqs-go/blob/main/examples/sig/sig.go, do they not work? What format/encoding do the keys you exported have? Post example keys.

OpenSSL needs to use private key in PKCS#8 format. So what needs to be done is to encode the key pair (private and public key) into this format.
It could be done like this:
package main

import (
      "crypto/x509/pkix"
      "encoding/asn1"
      "encoding/pem"
      "log"
      "os"

      "github.com/open-quantum-safe/liboqs-go/oqs"
)

var oidDilithium2 = asn1.ObjectIdentifier{1, 3, 6, 1, 4, 1, 2, 267, 7, 4, 4}

// pkcs8 reflects an ASN.1, PKCS #8 PrivateKey.
type pkcs8 struct {
    Version int
    Algo    pkix.AlgorithmIdentifier
    KeyPair []byte
}

func generateKeys() ([]byte, error) {
    // Initialize the signature algorithm, assuming `Dilithium2` is supported.
    signer := oqs.Signature{}
    err := signer.Init("dilithium2", nil)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer signer.Clean()

    publicKey, err := signer.GenerateKeyPair()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    secretKey := signer.ExportSecretKey()

    // Create keyPair bytes
    keyPair := append(secretKey, publicKey...)

    // Encode the key pair into ASN.1 format
    asn1Bytes, err := asn1.Marshal(keyPair)
    if err != nil {
         return nil, err
    }

    return asn1Bytes, nil
}

func convertKey(key []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    // Define the PKCS#8 structure
    pkcs8Key := pkcs8{
        Version: 0,
        Algo: pkix.AlgorithmIdentifier{
            Algorithm: oidDilithium2,
        },
        KeyPair: key,
    }

    // Marshal the PKCS#8 structure into ASN.1 format
    asn1PKCS8, err := asn1.Marshal(pkcs8Key)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return asn1PKCS8, nil
}

func writeKey(key []byte) error {
    // Encode ASN.1 bytes into PEM format with "PRIVATE KEY" type
    pemBlock := &pem.Block{
        Type:  "PRIVATE KEY",
        Bytes: key,
    }
    pemBytes := pem.EncodeToMemory(pemBlock)

    // Write the PEM-encoded key pair to a file
    err := os.WriteFile("priv.key", pemBytes, 0644)
    return err
}

func main() {
    // Generate Dilithium keys
    asn1Bytes, err := generateKeys()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to generate Dilithium key pair: %v", err)
    }

    // Convert key pair into PKCS#8 format
    keyFormatted, err := convertKey(asn1Bytes)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to convert Dilithium key pair into PKCS#8 format: %v", err)
    }

    // Write key to disk
    if err = writeKey(keyFormatted); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to write Dilithium key pair file: %v", err)
    }

    log.Println("Key pair generated successfully")
}

Now, with the private key file generated with the program, you can create CSR, Certificates...
Generate a self-signed certificate with OpenSSL and private key generated by liboqs-go:
openssl req -x509 -new -key priv.key -out ca.crt -nodes -subj "/CN=CA Dilthium2 with liboqs-go" -days 365

Read the generated certificate:
openssl x509 -in ca.crt -text

Here is the way to convert keys generated by liboqs-go into OpenSSL format, but if you want to use a public and private key generated by OpenSSL in your Go program, you can refer to this conversation, I already gave a solution: Aligning Key Sizes Between OpenSSL and liboqs-go for Signature Verification in Go
